# Are sets with 0 as an element not allowed to be a domain for f(x) = 1/x?

Tags: logic, algorithms, computer-science

Does a domain for a function mean that all its members have a defined output value? If this is so, is the distinction between a total function vs a partial function relevant to some arbitrary set, not to the domain itself?

Also, if a function is a total function of some set as its domain, does that mean that the set is a computable set? Is it impossible for a total function to not have an algorithm?

Comment: Yes, the domain of $f(x)$ is $\mathbb R \setminus \{ 0 \}$. See [Domain of a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function): "the *domain of definition* (or simply the domain) of a function is the set of all "input" or argument values for which the function is defined. "

Comment: See [Computable function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_function#Total_functions_that_are_not_provably_total) for discussion about total and non-computable.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks. If a set is decidable, does it mean there is a computable function that is total in regards to that set, and semi decidable if there is a computable function that is partial in regards to that set?

Answer (score 1):

> Does a domain for a function mean that all its members have a defined output value?

Yes, pretty much by definition. So the answer to question in the title is yes, as $1/0$ is not defined.

> If this is so, is the distinction between a total function vs a partial function relevant to some arbitrary set, not to the domain itself?

The writing $f:\subset X \to Y$ (i.e. $f$ is a partial function from $X$ to $Y$) means that $\mathrm{dom}(f)\subset X$. Every partial function $f$ is a total function $f:\mathrm{dom}(f)\to Y$.

> Also, if a function is a total function of some set as its domain, does that mean that the set is a computable set? Is it impossible for a total function to not have an algorithm?

Computability has nothing to do with totality. You can have total non-computable functions and partial computable functions over a non-computable set. E.g. the characteristic function $\chi_A$ of a non-computable set $A$ is total but not computable. On the other hand, the restriction of $\chi_A$ to $A$ is constantly $1$, hence computable.